# Find and Launch a program that matches a string

Tags: c++, file, vector, launcher

Looking for some help with the next step of my program.

What the program does now, is it asks the user for a which type of file they are looking for. Once the user answers it then searches the folder that the program is in and finds all the files with the extension that matches the requested type. It then lists all of those matching files with a number next to it that iterates with the search.

What I want to be able to do is have the user simply enter the number that corresponds with the file they want to open, and have it open.

What I have now it this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr2::sys;

    //Checks for matching extensions
bool ends_with(std::string& file, std::string& ext)
{
    return file.size() >= ext.size() && // file must be at least as long as ext
        // check strings are equal starting at the end
        std::equal(ext.rbegin(), ext.rend(), file.rbegin());
}
    //Checks for matching programs
bool program_match(std::string& file, std::string& reqFile)
{
    return std::equal(reqFile.begin(), reqFile.end(), file.begin());
}


void wScan( path f, unsigned i = 0 )
{
    directory_iterator d( f );
    directory_iterator e;
    vector<string>::iterator it2;
    std::vector<string> extMatch;
    std::vector<string> testMatch;

            //loop that populates the vector of matches
    for( ; d != e; ++d )
    {
        string file = d->path();
        string ext = ".docx";
        if(ends_with(file, ext))
        {
            extMatch.push_back(file);
        }

    }
    int preI = -1;
    for(it2 = extMatch.begin(); it2 != extMatch.end(); it2++)
    {
        preI += 1;
        cout << preI << ". " << *it2 << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter the number of your choice (or quit): ";
    int fSelection;
    cin >> fSelection;
                    //test match for full file match
        for( ; d != e; ++d )
    {
        string file = d->path();
        string reqFile = extMatch[fSelection];
        if(program_match(file, reqFile))
        {
            testMatch.push_back(file);
        }
    }
        for(it2 = extMatch.begin(); it2 != extMatch.end(); it2++)
    {
        cout << *it2 << endl;
    }

}
int main()
{

    string selection;
cout << "0. Microsoft word \n1. Microsoft Excel \n2. Visual Studio 11 \n3. 7Zip \n4. Notepad \n Enter the number of your choice (or quit): ";

cin >> selection;

path folder = "..";

    if (selection == "0")
{
    wScan ( folder );
}

    else if...
}
```

What I have now is another for loop that goes through the files again and pulls out all the files that match the one requested. It then prints out the names of that file. There is no reason for this, this was just a test to see if my method of searching would find the files I'm looking for.

I would like to know how to go about opening the file once it's found. I've read some stuff on system(), but it seems advised against and it didn't work for me the way I tried it anyway.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even notice the link and just read that as text, reading through that now. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to open a file in a specific program, say Excel, you can call the ShellExecute function in the Windows API with the right parameters. Here's some documentation for that function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx It's Window's specific, so it'll need porting to other systems.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but that seems to all be about opening a file for reading within c++. What I'm looking for is how to launch the program related to the file. For example, if I were to select test.docx it would then open up test.docx in Microsoft word.

Comment: Thanks for the link Ryan, looking into that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code will only be running on Windows (based on the programs listed), you can use the `ShellExecute` function. To use it, include `Windows.h` and pass the program and file you want to open to the function:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    char program[] = "VCExpress.exe";
    char file[] = "main.cpp";
    // opens file in program
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", program, file, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

`ShellExecute` also allows you to open a file in the default software associated to the file's extension. For me, the following also open in Visual C++:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    char file[] = "main.cpp";
    // opens file in default program
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", file, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

`ShellExecute` can execute a program with many more options; check out the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That works for opening up files, but the defualt directory it searches for them is in document. Would you happen to have any idea how to make it open files from the directory that the program is in? Reading your previous comment I see that the directory is the second last parameter, which when left NULL I suppose defaults to documents. I'm not sure how to make it my folder.

Comment: The default directory should be the working directory, unless something has changed it. To get the current directory, do something along the lines of: `char dir[MAX_PATH]; GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, dir); std::cout << dir << '\n';`. There is also a `SetCurrentDirectoryA` function to change the directory. See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Alright, I'm having some issues, but I'm sure I'll get it all figured out. Thank you very much, you've been a tremendous help!